# Why do I need a procfile for my heroku flask app but I didn't need a procfile for my heroku express.js or rails apps?

Tags: heroku, procfile

I've previously deployed apps on heroku written in Rails and in Express.js, and never come across the concept of a Procfile before. Now that I've just gone to deploy a Flask app, I discovered this Procfile concept and found that the app would not run correctly without it. The Heroku docs say nothing about this being Flask-specific, and imply it's needed for all apps.

What's up with that? Why didn't I need it before, but needed it now?

Answer (score 0):

In the `package.json` it tells Heroku how to execute the program. That's JavaScript specific. In other languages there is no such file hence the need for a `Procfile`.

Heroku needs to know how to execute your project.